# my app screen flashes after fetching audio files

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i am working on a media player app, and when fetching audio files, after some seconds, the screen flashes.

i think that when i bind the files to the recyclerView, the app can't do it in one try, so it flashes like that and resets.

on fun getSongs(), it saying that the function is never used.
and the code asks for a return there, but i don't exactly know what i return

i'm really sorry for bothering you

https://youtu.be/XamtQCejN-g video showing the bug

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.aplicativo_teste

import android.content.*
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.core.view.isGone
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.aplicativo_teste.Adapters.MusicAdapter
import com.example.aplicativo_teste.Modes.SongModel
import com.example.aplicativo_teste.Services.MusicService
import com.example.aplicativo_teste.`interface`.OnSongComplete
import com.example.aplicativo_teste.`interface`.onSongSelect
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.playmusic_layout.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.playmusic_layout.view.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), onSongSelect, View.OnClickListener, OnSongComplete {

    lateinit var list : ArrayList<SongModel>
    lateinit var adapter : MusicAdapter
    lateinit var musicService : MusicService
    lateinit var seekBar : SeekBar
    var playintent: Intent? = null

    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout>
    lateinit var songModel: SongModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bottomLayout.isGone = true

        list = ArrayList()

        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        recyclerview.layoutManager = manager
        adapter = MusicAdapter(list, applicationContext, this)
        recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        play_pause_btn_mini.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_previous_mini.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_next_mini.setOnClickListener(this)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomLayout)

        search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{ // Listener que detecta e lê o texto sendo digitado na edit text de pesquisa
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                searchSongs(p0.toString())                    // chama a função que retorna a música com base no que foi procurado na edittext na lista de pesquisa
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

        })
        getSongs()
    }

    /* Buscar música (retornar música do armazenamento)*/
    private fun getSongs() {
        val contentResolver = this.contentResolver
        val songUri =
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI // URI é o "link" no qual o cursor irá targetar e "puxar" pro aplicativo
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 60000", null, null) // "procurador"

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val songId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
            val songTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
            val songArtist = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
         // val songData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
         // val date = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED)
            val albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val currentId: Long = cursor.getLong(songId)
                var song_title: String = cursor.getString(songTitle)
                var song_artist: String = cursor.getString(songArtist)
           //   var song_data: String = cursor.getString(songData)
           //   var song_date: Long = cursor.getLong(date)
                var albumId: Long = cursor.getLong(albumColumn)

                val IMAGE_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
                val album_uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(IMAGE_URI, albumId)

                if (!songArtist.equals("<unknown>")) {
                    /* A adição da música seguirá uma classe modelo (classe SongModel) para organizar os dados da música no aplicativo */
                    list.add(
                        SongModel(
                            currentId,
                            song_title,
                            song_artist,
                     //       song_data,
                     //       song_date,
                            album_uri
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            cursor.close()
        }
    }

    /* Funcionalidade para procurar músicas pela barra de pesquisa */
    private fun searchSongs(value : String)
    {
        var songList = ArrayList<SongModel>()
        for(song : SongModel in list) {
            if(song.song_title.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()) || song.artist.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                songList.add(song)
            }
         /* if(song.artist.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())) {
                if(!isListAdded)                               // esse if causava um bug em que a música era duplicada na lista de pesquisa
                songList.add(song)                             // portanto eu coloquei o parâmetro dele junto ao if de cima com || "ou"
            } */
        }
        adapter.updateList(songList)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if(playintent == null)
        {
            playintent = Intent(this, MusicService::class.java)
            bindService(playintent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
            startService(playintent)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        stopService(playintent)
        unbindService(musicConnection)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun updateUI()
    {
        mini_player.minisong_title_bar.text = songModel.song_title
        mini_player.minisong_artist_name.text = songModel.artist
        bottomLayout.song_title_bar.text = songModel.song_title
        bottomLayout.song_artist_name.text = songModel.artist

        var bitmap : Bitmap? = null
        try {
            bitmap =
                MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, songModel.image)
            bottomLayout.songImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            mini_player.songImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }catch (e: Exception){

        }
    }

    private var musicConnection : ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection, OnSongComplete {
        override fun onServiceConnected(p0: ComponentName?, p1: IBinder?) {
            val binder : MusicService.MusicBinder = p1 as MusicService.MusicBinder
            musicService = binder.service
            musicService.setUi(bottomLayout.seekbar, bottomLayout.start_text, bottomLayout.end_text)
            musicService.setListener(this)
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {

        }

        override fun onSongComplete() {
            if(currentSong != -1){
                if(currentSong == 0)
                {
                    currentSong = list.size - 1
                    musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                    songModel = list[currentSong]
                    updateUI()

                }else{
                    currentSong--
                    musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                    songModel = list[currentSong]
                    updateUI()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSelect(song: SongModel) {
        musicService.setSong(song)
        songModel = song
        bottomLayout.isVisible = true
        updateUI()
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when(p0)
        {
            play_pause_btn ->
            {
                if(musicService.playerState == 2)
                {
                    // Pausa música
                    play_pause_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn_mini.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))

                    musicService.pauseSong()

                }else if(musicService.playerState == 1)
                {
                    // Retoma a música
                    play_pause_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn_mini.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))

                    musicService.resumeSong()
                }
            }
            play_pause_btn_mini ->
            {
                if(musicService.playerState == 2)
                {
                    // Pausa música
                    play_pause_btn_mini.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn_mini.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))

                    musicService.pauseSong()

                }else if(musicService.playerState == 1)
                {
                    // Retoma a música
                    play_pause_btn_mini.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_circle_filled_24)
                    play_pause_btn_mini.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))

                    musicService.resumeSong()
                }
            }
            btn_next ->
            {
                btn_next.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))
                if(list.size > 0){

                    if(currentSong != -1)
                        if(list.size - 1 == currentSong) {
                            currentSong = 0
                            musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                            songModel = list[currentSong]
                            seekBar.resetPivot()
                            updateUI()
                        }else{
                            ++currentSong
                            musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                            songModel = list[currentSong]
                            updateUI()
                        }
                }
            }
            btn_next_mini ->
            {
                btn_next_mini.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))
                if(list.size > 0){

                    if(currentSong != -1)
                        if(list.size - 1 == currentSong) {
                            currentSong = 0
                            musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                            songModel = list[currentSong]
                            seekBar.resetPivot()
                            updateUI()
                        }else{
                            ++currentSong
                            musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                            songModel = list[currentSong]
                            updateUI()
                        }
                }
            }
            btn_previous ->
            {
                btn_previous.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))
                if(currentSong != -1){
                    if(currentSong == 0)
                    {
                        currentSong = list.size - 1
                        musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                        songModel = list[currentSong]
                        updateUI()

                    }else{
                        currentSong--
                        musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                        songModel = list[currentSong]
                        updateUI()
                    }
                }
            }
            btn_previous_mini ->
            {
                btn_previous_mini.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, androidx.appcompat.R.anim.abc_fade_in))
                if(currentSong != -1){
                    if(currentSong == 0)
                    {
                        currentSong = list.size - 1
                        musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                        songModel = list[currentSong]
                        updateUI()

                    }else{
                        currentSong--
                        musicService.setSong(list[currentSong])
                        songModel = list[currentSong]
                        updateUI()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSongComplete() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

onCreate()

```
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bottomLayout.isGone = true

        list = ArrayList()

        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        recyclerview.layoutManager = manager
        adapter = MusicAdapter(list, applicationContext, this)
        recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        play_pause_btn_mini.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_previous_mini.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_next_mini.setOnClickListener(this)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomLayout)

        search_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{ // Listener que detecta e lê o texto sendo digitado na edit text de pesquisa
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                searchSongs(p0.toString())                    // chama a função que retorna a música com base no que foi procurado na edittext na lista de pesquisa
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

        })

        /* Buscar música (retornar música do armazenamento)*/
        fun getSongs(): List<SongModel> {

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val newSongList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    getSongs()
                }
                list.clear()
                list.addAll(newSongList)
            }

            val contentResolver = this.contentResolver
            val songUri =
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI // URI é o "link" no qual o cursor irá targetar e "puxar" pro aplicativo
            val cursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 60000", null, null) // "procurador"

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val songId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
                val songTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
                val songArtist = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
                val songDuration = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
                // val songData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
                // val date = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED)
                val albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)


                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val currentId: Long = cursor.getLong(songId)
                    var song_title: String = cursor.getString(songTitle)
                    var song_artist: String = cursor.getString(songArtist)
                    var song_duration: String = cursor.getString(songDuration)
                    //   var song_data: String = cursor.getString(songData)
                    //   var song_date: Long = cursor.getLong(date)
                    var albumId: Long = cursor.getLong(albumColumn)

                    val IMAGE_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
                    val album_uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(IMAGE_URI, albumId)

                    if (!songArtist.equals("<unknown>")) {
                        /* A adição da música seguirá uma classe modelo (classe SongModel) para organizar os dados da música no aplicativo */
                        list.add(
                            SongModel(
                                currentId,
                                song_title,
                                song_artist,
                                song_duration,
                                //       song_data,
                                //       song_date,
                                album_uri
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
                cursor.close()
            }
            return <????>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause of UI stutter / flickering is doing too much work on the UI thread. I think in your case its the function:

```
contentResolver.query(...)
```

That should be moved to a background thread instead of calling it directly in `onCreate()`.
The results of the query should be handed over to the UI via callback or stream.

In your example you could let your `getSongs()` function return a new list of songs every time you call it.
Then you can wrap the call on your `onCreate()` with a coroutine to move the heavy work to a background thread:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val newSongList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        getSongs()
    }
    list.clear()
    list.addAll(newSongList)
}
```

If `lifecycleScope` is not available you have to add a dependency to this androidx package:
`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx`

Comment: how can i wrap the call to onCreate()? i don't know how to exactly do that

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I meant you should wrap the `getSongs()` call inside the existing `onCreate()` function. Just replace it with the second code snipped I posted and return a new list from `getSongs()` like this:
`fun getSongs(): List<SongModel> {
    ...
}`.

Comment: man, i'm sorry, i just can't understand, i never did this before

Comment: i added the onCreate function on the question here, i did what i understand from what u said.

Comment: if you can just rewrite my code and explain it to me later, i think i would understand better.

Comment: i'm new at mobile, and programming in general, i using this app to a opportunity to study the code more deeply.

Comment: No problem. Every developer started as a newbie. I would advise you to learn how Java/Kotlin works before coming back to this problem. When you know what classes, methods/functions, member variables are it becomes much easier for you to modify the code like I said in my answer. And it becomes much easier to understand other projects (p. ex. sample projects on github).